# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) - React js

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I'm working on Spring Boot - React sample project. 
I was using the H2 database in the beginning and the API calls were working fine. However, the project outgrew the in-memory database and I shifted to MySQL. Ever since I've shifted to MySQL, my React front end has stopped working and I'm getting the console error as below. 
[image]

I'll admit I'm a beginner in React and would appreciate any help/hints.

My latest commit to the project was working as required. 
https://github.com/yrelhan/Project-Management-Tool/tree/branch2

I'd also like to confirm that I'm able to make all API calls from postman, so the endpoints are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error code says `401 (Unauthorized)`. This means that when you were trying to make an API call to your backend you have to provide some kind of authorization (maybe something specific for MySQL).